# How to interpret certain header fields in chrony's statistics and tracking log files?

Tags: gps, gpsd, chrony, pps

When generating the statistics and tracking logs from chrony, I see the following headers (along with the accompanying data):

Tracking:

**=== Date (UTC), Time,     IP Address,   St,   Freq ppm,   Skew ppm,     Offset, L, Co,  Offset sd, Rem. corr., Root delay, Root disp., Max. error ===**

Statistics:

**=== Date (UTC), Time,     IP Address,    Std dev'n, Est offset,  Offset sd,  Diff freq,   Est skew,  Stress,  Ns,  Bs,  Nr,  Asym ===**

For the tracking file, I'm trying to understand what the following mean:

- Co
- Rem. corr.
- Max. error

For the statistics file, I'm trying to understand the following:

- Est offset (vs the regular offset)
- Diff freq
- Stress
- Ns, Bs, Nr, and Asym

I'd appreciate any guidance or links to documentation that explains what these variables represent. Thanks.

I read through the chrony documentation online (https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/faq.html) and found good information on most of the fields in the tracking log; I could not find information on all of them, however. I was also not able to find much information on the header fields in the statistics log.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Thanks for asking!

I found this man page (after puzzling out some info from the online source, below)
[Ubuntu Manpage: chrony.conf - chronyd configuration file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/chrony.conf.5.html)

---

Earlier answer....

To move us in the right direction, I decided it was time to [Use the Source, Luke](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Use+the+Source%2C+Luke),
and found the [write_log() function in reference.c](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/120dfb8b36b942c31ddfc0220ca1475159ac5031/reference.c#L835C5-L835C5).

`reference.c` is the file that prints the `tracking.log` file, including the header you shared.

`Co` comes from the integer variable `combined_sources`, and seems to be the number of reference sources which are being used.

`Rem. corr.` comes from `uncorrected_offset`.

Other relevant tidbits include:

```
last_sys_offset = offset - uncorrected_offset;
...
max_error = orig_root_distance + fabs(last_sys_offset)
```

I'm still not sure what `Rem. corr.` or `max_error` really are, but perhaps this helps us decipher them.

[reference.h](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/master/reference.h) has some useful comments.

---

[sourcestats.c](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/master/sourcestats.c) produces the `statistics.log` file.

`Est offset` comes from `estimated_offset` about which it says this. I guess they may just be noting that they can only estimate the offset statistically, vs knowing the actual current value:

```
  /* This is the estimated offset (+ve => local fast) at a particular time */
  double estimated_offset;
```

The other values come from these variables:

`Diff freq`: `inst->estimated_frequency` /* This value contains the estimated frequency.  This is the number
of seconds that the local clock gains relative to the reference
source per unit local time.  (Positive => local clock fast,
negative => local clock slow) */

`Ns`: `inst->n_samples` /* Number of samples currently stored.  The samples are stored in circular buffer. */

`Bs`: `best_start`

`Nr`: `inst->nruns`   /* Number of runs of the same sign amongst the residuals */

`Asym`: `inst->asymmetry`   /* the latest estimated asymmetry of network jitter */

Again, [sourcestats.h](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/master/sourcestats.h) documents the functions, providing more hints.